# How to handle eof() in platform independent code? C++

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, eof

I have a c++ code where, I'm redirecting the stdout to a string. The code should be platform independent. In windows works fine, but under linux it doesn't builds.
Here is my code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int outBuffer[2];
int orgStdOutBuffer;
std::string stringBuff;
enum PIPES {READ, WRITE};
orgStdOutBuffer = dup(fileno(stdout));
outBuffer[READ] = 0;
outBuffer[WRITE] = 0;

if (_pipe(mStdOutBuffer, 65535, O_BINARY) == -1) {
        return false;
}
fflush(stdout);
dup2(outBuffer[WRITE], fileno(stdout));
```

The problem is where I'm checking the end of the pipe:

```
if (!eof(outBuffer[READ])) {
    stdOutBufferSize = read(outBuffer[READ], &(*stringBuff.begin()), buffSize);
}
```

Under linux gives the following error:

```
'eof' was not declared in this scope
'O_BINARY' was not declared in this scope
```

Can anybody help how can I make this code run under linux?

Comment: What *is* `eof`? There's no such global function in the C++ standard. Neither in the C standard, POSIX standard or anywhere else that I know of. And if that is your code, then you should be getting *more* errors. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And if you want to learn how to detect end-of-file from a file-descriptor, I suggest you read [the `read` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

Comment: read this http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2007-03/msg00147.html

Comment: But under windows is working fine and I get no errors. I tried do define a macro instead of O_BINARY, but in this way doesn't creates the pipe

Comment: If you mean `std::cout` instead of ` stdout`, it's far easier. You just splice in a `std::streambuf` from a `std::stringstream`.